# Connectivity with MS Access in java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

When I execute my java code, it give following error?

```
databasejava.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

Can you help me for the solution?

Comment: Could you give us your connect String?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using 32bit ODBC driver in 64 bit architecture, or vice versa.